# jQuery calculate in one function

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have a table something like this:

```
sellingprice   cost   postage  profit  paypal   ebayfees   discount    FVF
    ?           49     1.75     4.00     ?         ?           0.2      ?    
    ?           51     1.75     4.00     ?         ?           0.2      ?
```

This are the different formulas to solve the above information:

**sellingpriceresult** = cost + postage + profit + paypal + FVF; 
**paypalresult** = sellingpriceresult * 0.022 + 0.3; 
**FVFresult** = ebayfees - (ebayfees * discount); 
**ebayfeesresult** will be using if condition to display it's result, something like this:

if sellingpriceresult > 50 then (sellingpriceresult - 50) * 0.05 + 3.5

else if sellingpriceresult <= 50 then sellingpriceresult * 0.07

I want to implement the calculation using client-side computation. My problem is that i don't know how to combine all the calculation in a one function. I have a little bit idea about jQuery and want you guys to guide me how to perform this one. Any help would be much more appreciated.

Here is my sample code:

```
<table border = "0">    
            <tr>
                <td><center>Selling Price</center></td>
                <td><center>Cost</center></td>
                <td><center>Postage</center></td>
                <td><center>Profit</center></td>
                <td><center>Paypal</center></td>
                <td><center>eBay Fees</center></td>
                <td><center>Discount</center></td>
                <td><center>FVF</center></td>
            </tr> 
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type='text' id='sellingprice' name='sellingprice' size='10' readonly='true'/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='text' id='cost' name='cost' size='10' value='$myrow[1]' readonly='true'/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='text' id='postage' name='postage' size='10' value='1.75' readonly='true'/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='text' id='profit' name='profit' size='10' value='4.00' readonly='true'/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='text' id='paypal' name='paypal' size='10' readonly='true'/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='text' id='ebayfees' name='ebayfees' size='10' readonly='true'/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='text' id='discount' name='discount' size='10' value='0.2' readonly='true'/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='text' id='fvf' name='fvf' size='10' readonly='true'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>   
        </table>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('tr').each(function(){
            var sellingprice = 0;
            $(this).find("input[name=cost],input[name=postage],input[name=profit],input[name=paypal],input[name=fvf]").each(function(){
                sellingprice += (+$(this).val());
            });
            $(this).find("input[name=sellingprice]").val(sellingprice).css("background-color", "yellow");
            });     
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){   
            $('tr').each(function(){
            var paypal = 0;
            $(this).find("input[name=sellingprice]").each(function(){
                paypal = (+$(this).val()) * 0.022 + 0.3;
                paypal = paypal.toFixed(2);
            });
            $(this).find("input[name=paypal]").val(paypal).css("background-color", "yellow");
            }); 
        });


        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('tr').each(function(){
            var sellingprice = 0;
            $(this).find("input[name=cost],input[name=postage],input[name=profit],input[name=paypal],input[name=fvf]").each(function(){
                sellingprice = (+$(this).val());
                sellingprice = sellingprice.toFixed(2);
            });
            $(this).find("input[name=sellingprice]").val(sellingprice).css("background-color", "yellow");
            });     
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('tr').each(function(){
            var fvf = 0;
            $(this).find("input[name=ebayfees],input[name=discount]").each(function(){
                fvf = (+$(this).val());
            });
            $(this).find("input[name=fvf]").val(fvf).css("background-color", "yellow");
            }); 
        });


        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('tr').each(function(){
            var sellingprice = 0;
            $(this).find("input[name=cost],input[name=postage],input[name=profit],input[name=paypal],input[name=fvf]").each(function(){
                sellingprice += (+$(this).val());
            });
            $(this).find("input[name=sellingprice]").val(sellingprice).css("background-color", "yellow");
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('tr').each(function() {
                var sellingpriceResult = parseFloat($(this).find("input[name=sellingprice]").val());

                var result = 0;
                if (sellingpriceResult > 50) { 
                    result = (sellingpriceResult - 50) * 0.05 + 3.5;
                    result = result.toFixed(2);
                }
                else {
                    result = sellingpriceResult * 0.07;
                    result = result.toFixed(2);
                }
                $(this).find("input[name=ebayfees]").val(result).css("background-color", "yellow");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: The value of the cost is `$myrow[1]`... I'm guessins it's a typoh.

Comment: Because the cost is being fetch in the database to fill in the cost column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note 1**: I'm guessing there is going to be several rows so you have to remove the ID attributes from your inputs because ID must be unique within an HTML document.

**Note 2**: I'm not sure to completely understand the calculation you want to make. "Selling price" depends on "FVF", "FVF" depends on "Ebay fees" and "Ebay fees" depends on "Selling price"... Seems a bit impossible to me to calculate with this recursive dependency

**Note 3**: You are using a `insertionfee` element in your example but i's not in the markup you provided.

Some notes on the following code:

- get a jquery object for the current `<tr>` for re-use with `$this = $(this)`
- find all your needed elements for re-use as well. besides it is more efficient thanks to `$this`
- doing this `$item.val(myvariable = 1+1)` actually saves the calculation into `myvariable` and pass it to `.val()`
- this `condition ? <if condition true> : <if condition false>` allows you to make inline conditionnal statements
- i was not able to use `.toFixed(2)`, i guess it is a function of yours

I have made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/zN4uY/) for you to see.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('tr').each(function() {

        var $this = $(this),
            $sellingprice = $this.find('[name=sellingprice]'),
            $cost = $this.find('[name=cost]'),
            $postage = $this.find('[name=postage]'),
            $profit = $this.find('[name=profit]'),
            $paypal = $this.find('[name=paypal]'),
            $ebayfees = $this.find('[name=ebayfees]'),
            $discount = $this.find('[name=discount]'),
            $fvf = $this.find('[name=fvf]');

        var selpriceresult, paypalresult, fvfresult, ebayresult;

        $sellingprice.val((selpriceresult = $cost.val() + $postage.val() + $paypal.val() + $fvf.val()));
        $paypal.val(paypalresult = selpriceresult * 0.022 + 0.3);

        $ebayfees.val(ebayresult = selpriceresult > 50
                        ? (selpriceresult - 50) * 0.05 + 3.5
                        : selpriceresult * 0.07);

        $fvf.val(fvfresult = ebayresult - (ebayresult - $discount.val()));

});
```

---

**About the formulas**

I have checked the excel file. This is not as easy as it seems. The formulas have dependencies and I have no idea how excel is really performing the calculations internally.

I known excel builds and optimize a *Dependencies Tree* to determine how it should perform the calculations of a workbook. You can sort-of visualize the dependencies and the relations between cells (Tools > Audit) but i'm not an excel guru and it's completely out of my knowledge.

I think this is also a bit out of the scope of this question - which was to combine jquery code blocks into one, not to *convert* excel formulas to javascript computation.

I am really willing to help you out on the calculations too but I just can't. You can maybe ask another question about this particular subject.

Comment: Note 3: Sorry about the insertionfee in my markup i removed it already. That's not included in the markup.

Comment: Yeah that's true. Sellingprice depends on the output of paypal and fvf. ebayfees and paypal both depends in the output of sellingprice. Can you guide me till i got the correct calculation of this problem.

Comment: I don't know how I can guide you to determine the formulas, you are the one who knows what they are. I can only guide you on how to write them in code.

Comment: Can you reconstruct the code you've shared to me to solve this particular issues where sellingpriceresult = cost + postage + profit + paypal + fvf. paypalresult = sellingpriceresult * 0.022 + 0.3. ebayfeesresult will depends if the sellingpriceresult is greater or less than 50. Some outputs like in the sellingpriceresult depends in   paypal and fvf result. Can you share/guide me some  specific codes with this issue?

Comment: The jsfiddle you've shared to me seems not the exact output of this problem. sellingpriceresult gets the output if you add cost, postage, profit, paypal and fvf. paypalresult and ebayfeesresult will display base in the sellingpriceresult output.

Comment: It just makes no sense. How can you calculate "sellingpriceresult" if you need "paypalresult" and need "sellingpriceresult" to calculate "paypalresult"... You have to explain a bit more clearer because i don't get it... Edit you question and explain step by step your formulas (for example).

Comment: http://j-mobileapps.6te.net/problem%20about%20calculation.xlsx - Can you view or download this excel file sir this probably my problem that needs some guides on how to implement

Comment: Could you give me some ideas how to break down this big problem in my calculation? I mean is there any way to automate this excel file base on the calculation being presented?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Really i cannot help you more with the excel part.